# Laravel Concatenar campos en una misma tabla; nombre completo

Tags: laravel

Mi duda es la siguiente tengo una tabla con la estructura

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('docentes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('idDocente',20);
        $table->string('apellido1', 40);
        $table->string('apellido2', 40);
        $table->string('nombre1', 40);
        $table->string('nombre2', 40)->nullable();
        $table->date('fechaNac');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('nivel_id');
        $table->foreign('nivel_id')->references('id')->on('niveles');
        $table->string('direccion', 80);
        $table->string('telefono', 16);
        $table->string('email', 80)->unique();
        $table->set('tipo',['Profesor','Asesor'])->default('Profesor');
        $table->string('nombre',100);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

[image: Esta es la vista del create]

Lo que deseo hacer es unir los campos apellido1, apellido2,nombre1,nombre2 en el campo nombre de la misma tabla, esto lo hago ya que en muchas ocasiones voy a tener que traer la consulta del nombre del profesor que se relaciona con otras vistas y aunque se que puedo hacer esto para mostrar la consulta

```
<td>{{$grupo->docente->apellido1}} {{$grupo->docente->apellido2}} {{$grupo->docente->nombre1}}</td>
```

me parece mas limpio si lo hiciera

```
<td>{{$grupo->docente->nombre}}</td>
```

Como puedo lograr que ese campo se cargue por defecto cuando llenen los campos apellido1, apellido2, nombre1, nombre2 en el formulario, tengo en el modelo esta función para concatenar los campo

```
 public function getNombreCompletoAttribute()
 {
     return $this->apellido1 . ' ' . $this->apellido2 . ' ' . $this->nombre1. ' ' . $this->nombre2;
 }
```

Pero soy nuevo en Laravel y no sé donde debo llamar esa función si en la vista o en el controlador y como debo invocarla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes invocarla donde tu desees.

Cuando tu creas una función con el prefijo `get` y el sufijo `Attribute`, estas creando un nuevo atributo dentro de tu modelo, para acceder a el solo debes de llamarlo como harias con cualquier otro atributo.

```
<td>{{$grupo->docente->nombre_completo}}</td>
```

La separación con el guion bajo es porque declaraste al tributo `NombreCompleto`, un guion bajo se aplica desde la segunda mayuscula que se encuentre.

Comment: Gracias. Una pregunta el campo nombre que puse en la tabla dentro de la base de datos, está demás, ese campo iba a contener el nombre completo en un solo dato, pero no es necesario solo llamar la función?. Creo que hay era donde estaba enredado

Comment: @juandavidzambrano es suficiente con hacer la funcion `set` de nombre, para que este contenga todo el nombre, investiga un poco de funciones mutadores en laravel, te serviria mucho.